# how to use a simple Relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables like below:

`users` table:

```
id - fname - lname
```

`users_projects` table:

```
id - user_id - title
```

my models are inside a directory called `Models`:

`Users` model :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    //

    public function usersProjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UsersProjects::class);
    }
}
```

`UsersProjects` model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UsersProjects extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users_projects';
    //

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Users::class);
    }
}
```

now, I want to show last projects :

```
    $projects    = UsersProjects::limit(10)->offset(0)->get();

    var_dump($projects);
    return;
```

but my `var_dump` shows last projects ! I want to have `fname` and `lname` ! where is my wrong ?

Comment: each user can have some projects. now, I want to show projects .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have your relationships set up a little wrong. If a user can have more than one project, in your user model ...

```
public function usersProjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UsersProjects::class);
}
```

You might want to use a little simpler naming too ...

```
public function Projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserProject::class);
}
```

(or simply Project if you don't have any other "Project" models)

The in your "Project" class ...

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

(assuming you rename your model to User instead of "Users". Your table name should be "users" but a model is by nature a singular object. So it's appropriate to call it "User" - and your UsersProjects model should just be UserProject or just Project)

Now if you call the method something other than "User" you will have to add the foreign key name ...

```
public function SomeOtherName()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Then ...

```
$projects = Project::with('User')->limit(10)->offset(0)->get();
```

Will return a collection of projects with the User eager-loaded. (assuming you have renamed your UsersProjects model to "Project")

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    ...
    First Name: {{ $project->User->fname }}
    ...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify the relationships between the tables? (one to one, one to many) at first sight, I think that the relations are wrong

Comment: each user can have some projects. now, I want to show projects .